# Coordenadas de área selecionada em imagem

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte dúvida:

Tenho uma imagem e quero fazer a seleção de uma área qualquer dessa imagem, como no exemplo marcado pelo quadrado vermelho (considere que isso seja a seleção).

Dessa seleção, preciso saber qual a coordenada de cada um dos pontos, como por exemplo na imagem: Ponto 01 = Coordenada XY | Ponto 02 .....

Alguém pode me dar uma ideia de como faço isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse quadrado vem de onde? é uma div que arrastas para essa posição ou é uma parte da imagem?

Comment: Então @Sergio, vem de uma parte da imagem. A ideia seria selecionar qualquer parte da imagem com um "select area" igual aos selects de crop, só que ai invés de fazer o crop, retornaria os pontos indicados.

Comment: Não percebo bem ainda... dizes que vem de uma parte da imagem, mas que a ideia seria selecionar qualquer parte da imagem. O rectangulo vermelho faz parte do `jpg`, `png` **ou** foi criado no browser com interação do utilizador?

Comment: Criado no browser com interação do utilizador. Acabei encontrando uma utilização prática no plugin Cropper. Dê uma olhada [link](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/) - X, Y, Width, Width, que são as informações que preciso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui fica um ponto de partida para fazer isso com JavaScript nativo.

Não é dificil, o meu exemplo pode precisar de uns ajustes mas assim aprendes melhor também como funciona.

Basicamente precisas de controlar alguns parâmetros:

- saber quando e onde o mouse clica na imagem para começar a arrastar
- saber onde o mouse se move e cancelar o drag nativo
- ir mudando a largura da selecao à medida que se arrasta
- juntar o auscultador de evento do `mousemove` à window, para saber quando o arraste acaba
- usar o `getBoundingClientRect` para saber as posições dos cantos da selecao

Esse passos estão no código abaixo, isso na prática poderia ser assim:

JavaScript:

```js
var info = document.getElementById('info');
var img = document.querySelector('img');
var selecao = document.getElementById('selecao');

var inicio;

function arrastador(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    selecao.style.width = e.pageX - inicio.x + 'px';
    selecao.style.height = e.pageY - inicio.y + 'px';
    gerarInfo();
}

function gerarInfo() {
    var pos = selecao.getBoundingClientRect();
    var coords = {
        se: [pos.left, pos.top],
        sd: [pos.right, pos.top],
        ie: [pos.left, pos.bottom],
        id: [pos.right, pos.bottom]
    };
    info.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(coords);
}
img.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    inicio = {
        x: e.pageX,
        y: e.pageY
    };
    selecao.style.display = 'block';
    selecao.style.left = inicio.x + 'px';
    selecao.style.top = inicio.y + 'px';
    selecao.style.width = 0;
    selecao.style.height = 0;
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', arrastador);
});
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    inicio = null;
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', arrastador);
    gerarInfo();
});
```

CSS:

```css
#selecao {
    border: 2px #aaf solid;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="info">Aqui vai aparecer info...</div>
<img src="http://images6.mygola.com/518e281853db45a2b7fe72a008e3b54a_1394089229_l.jpg" alt="" />
<div id="selecao"></div>
```

## jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/akncqxht/2

No exemplo os resultados são

- "canto superior direito" como `se`
- "canto superior esquerdo" como `sd`
- etc

Se tiveres dúvidas diz que explico melhor.

Comment: Solução perfeita amigo! Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Esta de parabéns!

Answer (score 1):

encontrei uma solução prática no plugin Cropper. Ele retorna exatamente essas informações da imagem. Seleção feita no browser com interação do utilizador. Retorna as coordernadas X, Y, Width e Height.

https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/